I see spans on localhost in spite of changed URL in application.properties
I'm configuring tracing for Spring Boot 3.3 and Zipkin, but despite my configuration, I'm still seeing my spans being reported to localhost:9411. Below is my configuration and dependencies setup. How do I overcome this? Providing the details:
logging.level.io.zipkin=DEBUG
logging.level.io.micrometer=DEBUG
management.tracing.propagation.type=b3
management.zipkin.tracing.endpoint=http://myhomeserverip:9411/api/v2/spans
management.tracing.enabled=true
management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0
logging.level.zipkin2=DEBUG

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


Those exclusions for spring-boot-starter-logging are really weird especially for dependencies that will not even depend on Spring. What I would do is stopping the auo-configuration of the Zipkin Reporter with my debugger and check the property value and state of the Environment. Something might override your property or it could be never read since the file name or the path of it is wrong.
